# Accessing a database inside an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Is it possible to create a database server (MySQL or PostgreSQL) inside an EC2 instance (running Windows 2016) and access it the way we access an RDS or do I need to have a separate RDS for that purpose?

My plan was to have an EC2 instance and use it as a server for accessing some Windows applications to my (small) company as well as an always-available database to store our reports.

Please let me know if I am on the wrong path.

Comment: If RDS fulfill you're required suggest go with RDS service. Manage DB services in Windows really hectic. you can make it secure or accessibility to your office or application only.

Comment: @JogendraKumar you are right. But I cannot use a Windows application with RDS alone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can install MySQL or PostgreSQL on an EC2 instance, just like you would for a server that was within your company.

You of course won't have all of the extra redundancy/backup features that RDS provides for you - unless you start adding all of that yourself  i.e. automated backups, slave/master configurations, read replicas etc. (and if you do start adding all of those extra features in I would reconsider your decision not to use RDS).

I do this for some smaller, less mission critical solutions I support, and generally have not had many issues; I still prefer RDS when possible, but its not always an option for me.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. So is it possible to reach that database inside EC2 from outside (e.g. via Management Studio, MySQL Workbench or pgAdmin) without logging into the EC2?

Comment: Yes, that will work fine but important to limit the range of ip addresses that can do this if possible and make sure you use very strong passwords. Its a security risk, but technologically it will work fine.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again. I will launch an RDS as soon as the need grows. But I guess I can live with an EC2 instance with a small database server for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and configure DB on windows and access from your app. the endpoint will be windows machine IP and running service port. you have to allow the application from the security group.